# Rendering new component on click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm practicing react and trying to render a new component on click of a button. Here the first page is email and the component i want to render contains password page.

```js
  class App extends React.Component {
 passwordpage(){
    return(
      <form>
        <div className="mainapp">
          <h2> Password</h2>
          <input type='Password' className="inputpassword" placeholder='Enter Password' required/>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" className="loginbutton">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="mainapp">
          <h2>Email  Id</h2>
          <input type='email' ref='enteremail'className="inputemail" placeholder='Enter Username' required/>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.props.passwordpage} className="loginbutton">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    );
  }
}

 ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Could you add more details please, for exampe, the function that you pass via props (button's onClick function) what's the code in it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to have the password page already prepared in your `render()`,
and to show/hide it depending on the component state, that is mutated by the `onClick` handler, something along those lines:

```
showPasswordPage() {
  this.setState({showPassword: true });
}

render() {
  const passwordPage = (<form>
    <div className="mainapp">
      <h2> Password</h2>
      <input type='Password' className="inputpassword" placeholder='Enter Password' required/>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" className="loginbutton">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>);

  const mainForm = (<form>
    <div className="mainapp">
      <h2>Email  Id</h2>
      <input type='email' ref='enteremail'className="inputemail" placeholder='Enter Username' required/>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.showPasswordPage} className="loginbutton">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>);

  return { this.state.showPassword ? passwordPage : mainForm };
```

Comment: I implemented above stated code, it's showing some error but m not able to debug it

Comment: error : 'Unexpected token' in this line....   { this.state.showPassword ? passwordPage : mainForm };

Comment: did you initialize `this.state` with `{ showPassword: false }` in your constructor ?

Comment: yeah i did. Somehow i got rid of error but then the state is not changing, m getting same email page upon click

Comment: got the issue...actually the page is working fine without entering email in text field, but when entering and clicking next button the page is refreshing again. As a result getting email page. how to get rid of it?

Comment: This is because you use `button type="submit"` ; why `submit` ? With the code you are showing us it makes no sense - remove type submit and see if it solves your problem. I would put a `onClick` hanlder on the button, and act accordingly (like, doing a request to the server to validate username/password)

Answer (score 2):

I usually keep some variables in state and change them based on user action.

So in your case I have stored the current active page e.g `usernamePage` and when user clicks next I show another page in your case it is `passwordPage`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isPasswordPage : false,
      isUsernamePage : true,
      username       : "",
      password       : ""
    };

    this.enablePasswordPage  = this.enablePasswordPage.bind(this);
  }

  enablePasswordPage() {
    this.setState({
      isPasswordPage : true,
      isUsernamePage : false
    });
  }
  
  passwordpage(){
    return(
      <form>
        <div className="mainapp">
          <h2> Password</h2>
          <input type='Password' className="inputpassword" placeholder='Enter Password' required/>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" className="loginbutton">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  };

  render() {
    var usernameComp = (
      <form>
        <div className="mainapp">
          <h2>Email  Id</h2>
          <input type='email' ref='enteremail'className="inputemail" placeholder='Enter Username' required/>
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.enablePasswordPage} className="loginbutton">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
    
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.isUsernamePage ? usernameComp : null }
        { this.state.isPasswordPage ? this.passwordpage() : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to make use of `react-router` and then create separate components for each of the Page that you want to display. That is the best possible way to achieve what you want to do.

You components will look something like

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.props.children}</div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  handleClick = (e) => {
     e.stopPropagation();
     browserHistory.push('/passwordPage');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div className="mainapp">
          <h2>Email  Id</h2>
          <input type='email' ref='enteremail'className="inputemail" placeholder='Enter Username' required/>
          <div>
            <button className="loginbutton" onClick={this.handleClick}>Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    );
  }
}

class PasswordPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <form>
        <div className="mainapp">
          <h2> Password</h2>
          <input type='Password' className="inputpassword" placeholder='Enter Password' required/>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" className="loginbutton">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Home}>
    <IndexRoute component={App} />
    <Route path="/passwordPage" component={PasswordPage} />
   </Route>
   </Router>
)
```

Look at the react-router docs **[here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router)**