# Rendering a new class in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, state

I want a way to show a classes render method due to an onclick event.
I have a log in page, once the uses completes it and hits submit (aka logs in), I want a new view to render.

```
  class LoginPage extends React.Component{
       render() {

    return (
      <div id="container">
            <button onClick={() => this.refs.myref.myfunc()}>Click</button>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleClick}>
                <p><input type="text" id="playerName" value={this.props.nameValue} onChange={this.handleNameChange} /></p>
                <p><input type="email" id="playerEmail"  value={this.props.emailValue} onChange={this.handleEmailChange}/></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="submit" /></p>
              </form>
            </div>
    )
  }
 }

    class HomePage extends React.Component{
    //does things
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1 className="headings" id="heading"> Home Page </h1>
          </div>
        )
      }
  }
```

How can I render the Home Page title instead of the form. I used to have some code that would toggle it based on state but now I am trying to break it into components and only set state in one place.
The `handleClick` function was updating the state before but now it is doing nothing but I want it to in some way call the render method inside the homepage component or pass state/props around. what is the react way of doing this? can further clarify if things do not make sense

Comment: create a fiddle

Comment: You can use react-router to navigate to a new page in a single page app, can refer to this solution SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715669/rendering-new-component-on-click-in-react/40715948#40715948